# Run time optimisation

Tags: java, optimization, file-io, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I need to read from a text file, replace all "," with "\n", and write the result to a new text file. My text file is large (16MB), and it takes few hours to complete this task. Is there any other way to implement it faster?

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "file1.txt";  // The name of the file to open.
        String s="";                // This will reference one line at a time

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
        int c, n=0;
        char character;

        while((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
           character = (char) c;
           if ( character == ',')
               s = s + "\n";
           else
               s += character;
        }
        reader.close();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("fileName1.txt");

        out.println(s);   
        out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any other way to implement it faster?

The primary bottleneck is this statement:

```
       if ( character == ',')
           s = s + "\n";
       else
           s += character;
```

Basically, you are doing a string concatenation for every single character in your input file.  If there are N characters in the file, you are creating N strings, and the concatenations are *copying* roughly `N * (N + 1) / 2` characters.  If N is `16,000,000`, then you are talking about a *huge* number of characters copied.  (And a lot of garbage collection too.)

If you simply wanted to avoid the concatenation, the solution would be to replace `String s` with `StringBuilder s` ... and use the `append` operation to build the output string.

But the best solution in this case is to open a `BufferedWriter` for the output file and write the characters directly to that ... without building an in-memory string.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

> What do you mean?

I mean something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("in.txt"));
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt"))) {
        int c;
        char character;
        while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
            character = (char) c;
            if (character == ',')
                writer.write('\n');
            else
                writer.write(character);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using the Java 7 "try with resource" syntax.  The resources (i.e. the streams) will be automatically closed on completion of the try-catch-finally statement.

Comment: What do you mean? If there is a way not to use String, it will be better. How can I read from the output file, change "," to '/n' and write the characters directly to that?

Answer (score 3):

1. Instead of reading character by character, read line by line.
2. For each line read, replace all commaa with "\n" by calling [replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.
3. Use BufferedWriter

Comment: The first two ideas probably won't help.  Character by character processing is most likely fastest ... provided you don't try to store the whole lot in memory.

Comment: I'd be pretty impressed if Java abstracted away the speed difference between loading large chunks of the file and bytes.

Comment: @MattBryant - The `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` should take care of that.  There might be faster ways (using NIO / CharBuffer, etc) but character by character processing is "close enough".  It should reduce the runtime to (say) a few seconds.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks.  I'm significantly more used to C IO.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Unix of some sort, you can just use the command line for this.

```
sed 's/,/\n/g' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, now is much better!

Comment: I've done it but used this command "cat ~/Desktop/file1.txt | tr "," "\n"  > ~/Desktop/output.txt" Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The time is spent concatenating strings. There's no need to do that. You can write out each line as you finish processing it, or indeed each character: if the latter, make sure you wrap the `FileWriter` in a `BufferedWriter.`